How can I export a a blender material as an .MDL file?
I'm very new to Blender and 3D in general. I've been using blender in combination with Adobe Dimension because Dimension it's more intuitive. I created a material in blender and when I import the .OBJ file to dimension, it doesn't recognize the material.
Is there an updated .MDL exporter plugin for Blender? I can only find old versions created for world of warcraft that don't seem to be working on blender 4.1.
I figured Dimension works with .MDL files but if you can think of another solution, let me know.
Thank you!

Except for a few particular cases you can't generally export materials. See https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/57531/fbx-export-why-there-are-no-materials-or-textures Otherwise if you believe your material should be exporting and it doesn't, please show its settings and node setup so we can evaluate
